# can not find the save action when magento submit a form

Tags: php, forms, magento

I'm new to magento, and I'm confused how magento handle forms.
I'm using sample data given by magento
In my admin panel, I go to catalog,manage product, and try to figure out how magento save those form data to database. let's say I edit the item which id=881, from the url, when render the page,they use `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml for the template,` and in this file, there is lines of code

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" id="product_edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <div style="display:none"></div>
</form>
```

and i tried to find out which action script specified to handle this post form, I echo it to the page and got something like `localhost/magento/index.php/admin/catalog_product/save/id/881/key/d092b22cecaae47664a8c9f9eea63a50/`, I think admin is the namesapce, catalog_product is the controllers' name, and save should be the action name, and I look for the file located in `Mage_Catalog_controllers_ProductController.php` and i can not find the save action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin is your module name, which should give away where you should be looking for the controller,

If you open up `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\etc\config.xml`,

you will notice,

```
#FIle :82
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Adminhtml</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Notice, `<frontName>admin</frontName>`

thus for above path of the controller is,

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php
```

will give you the actions related to product in admin, same way you can track your blocks, helpers and models.